# как сохранять в БД поле author_Id ? Laravel

Tags: laravel

есть 2 таблицы

```
Profiles
id
author_id

users
id
name
```

как сделать чтобы при сохранении нового Profile author_id заполнялся залогиненным id пользователя?

спасибо!

сохраняется оно тут это контроллер voyager который находится в vendor

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $slug = $this->getSlug($request);

        $dataType = Voyager::model('DataType')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

        // Check permission
        $this->authorize('add', app($dataType->model_name));

        // Validate fields with ajax
        $val = $this->validateBread($request->all(), $dataType->addRows)->validate();
        $data = $this->insertUpdateData($request, $slug, $dataType->addRows, new $dataType->model_name());

        event(new BreadDataAdded($dataType, $data));

        if (!$request->has('_tagging')) {
            if (auth()->user()->can('browse', $data)) {
                $redirect = redirect()->route("voyager.{$dataType->slug}.index");
            } else {
                $redirect = redirect()->back();
            }

            return $redirect->with([
                'message'    => __('voyager::generic.successfully_added_new')." {$dataType->getTranslatedAttribute('display_name_singular')}",
                'alert-type' => 'success',
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['success' => true, 'data' => $data]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А где и как происходит сохранение "нового Profile"?

Comment: сохраняется админкой voyager, 
я вот нашел, что  можно в модели Profile установить 


protected $attributes = [
       'author_id' => 'Test',
    ]; //так работает, но мне нужно динамичесмки же менять author_id так как пользователи же меняются

Comment: а вот так ругается
protected $attributes = [
        'author_id' => Auth::user()->role->id,
    ];

Comment: Код в вопрос нужно добавлять, и при чем тут $attributes? Они же описывают колонки только.

Comment: я присвоил значение  protected $attributes = [ 'author_id' => 'Test', ]; //так работает, и при сохранении колонка author_id заполняется Test

Comment: @Yaroslav Molchan ДОПОЛНИЛ ВОПРОС ТАМ ЭТОТ КОНТРОЛЛЕР УНИВЕРСАЛЬНЫЙ Т.Е ДЛЯ ВСЕХ МОДЕЛЕЙ А МНЕ НУЖНО ТОЛЬКО ДЛЯ PROFILE